# Find the equation of the plane given a line and a point

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, plane-geometry

I’m trying to solve a problem where i have to find the plane equation that contains a given straight line and a given point.

In this photo you can see the equation of the straight Line and the given point $P = (1,-2,3)$.
The answer of the problem is the last Line.
[image]
What i tried is this:

0. transform the straight line into parametric form
1. find the director parameters of the straight line $V = ( L,m,n)$
2. find a point of the straight line $Q = ( f, g, h)$
3. find the vector $PQ$.
4. do the vector product of the vectors $V$ and $PQ$ that gives me the director parameters of the plane that I'm searching.

The problem is that at this point what i find is that the director parameters of the plane are
$N = ( -\frac{1}{3}, \frac{10}{3}, -\frac{14}{9})$ that are different from the solution ones.

Can anyone show me how to solve this problem so i can check and understand where I’m doing it wrong?

Comment: I suggest you this way: Find the pencils of planes such that $H_{\alpha, \beta}=\alpha (2x-3y+z-3)+\beta (x+3y+2z+1)=0$. Then, you have to impose that $P=(1,-2,3) \in H_{\alpha, \beta}$ and you find the two values of your parameters that define the plane you were looking for.

Comment: I hope my answer will help you. I'm not understanding how you found the orthogonal vector that defines the plane.

Comment: @psidaga  Thanks for your answer! I get the ortogonal vector in this way: Once that i Found V and PQ I know that they are on the same plane ( that is the one that i’m searching ) so by doing the vectorial Product of V and PQ i get another vector N that is ortogonal to the plane indetified by V and PQ. So the components of N are the ones that define the plane. no?

Comment: It sounds ok...The general equation of a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with a given orthogonal vector  $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and a point $P=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ is $v_1(x-p_1)+v_2(y-p_2)+v_3(z-p_3)=0$.  Are you sure that you did the substitution with the vector you found correctly?

Comment: If you mean the substitution of the ortogonal vector N in the plane equation i didn’t do it. I thought that was usless becouse the N components had to be the same of the solution one so also by placing them in the equation wouldn’t solve anything

Comment: @psidaga if you have time can you try to solve it in the same way i tried? Just for understand if it is a simple calculation error

Comment: It is a simple calculation error, I just did it using your method and it worked

Comment: Thanks @Flutterblaxi

Comment: With "substitution" I wanted to say the correct use of your vector in the formula I wrote of a general plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a real quick method:

Find the pencil of planes such that $H_{\alpha, \beta}=\alpha (2x-3y+z-3)+\beta (x+3y+2z+1)=0$ 
(all these are planes that have the line given by the exercise in common).

Then, you have to impose that $P=(1,-2,3) \in H_{\alpha, \beta}$.

This condition gives us $\alpha (2+6+3-3)+ \beta (1+6-6+1)=0$ $\implies$ $\beta= -4\alpha$.

If we now substitute $(\alpha , \beta)=(1,-4)$ in the equation of $H_{\alpha, \beta}$ we have $2x-3y+z-3-4x-12y-8z-4=0$, so

$$2x+15y+7z+7=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is part of the solution using your method:[image: Solution]

Comment: Don't post pictures. Although I can read it, my eyes hurt. Please use MathJax.

Comment: It would have been very long to write, the person who asked the question needed a quick response and the image is very clear so I don't see why not.

Comment: I have already told you. Furthermore, it isn't searchable. Both the question and the answers must be searchable. I'm not the downvoter, but you should read the site's guidelines. The _clarity_ is dispitable. I can read most of your post, but only most.

Comment: I agree but since these are just the calculations I used to solve **this** particular problem, I thought posting a picture was the best/quickest way to be helpful. Nobody is going to search **these** specific calculations.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was helpfull, i have just a little question, why you preferred to find the parametric form using z = t instead of x = t? Or y =t? Was for a specific reason?

Comment: @Mat.C No, it's just that I had made some calculation mistakes using x=t and I noticed that choosing z=t the numbers were slightly better so I solved it that way. It makes no difference at all

Answer (score 0):

If you want another way (but a little informal) to do it, you can do this:
Give $z=1$, for example, then, you'll have the system
$\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc} 2x-3y=2\\ x+3y=-3\end{array}\right.$.
If you solve the sistem, you wil find a point that belongs to the line. Give $z=0$, then, the new system is 
$\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc} 2x-3y=3\\ x+3y=-1\end{array}\right.$.
Newly, solve the system.
Thus, you have three points of the plane that you want. With them, you can find the equation of the plane.